# extract digits from string using Regex in c++

Tags: c++, regex

I have created this c++ to extract digits from mixed strings limited by xxx and yyy
Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string text = "xxx1111yyy xxxrandomstring2222yyy";

    string start_delimiter = "xxx";

    string end_delimiter = "yyy";

    regex pattern(start_delimiter + "([0-9]+)" + end_delimiter);

    smatch match;

    while (regex_search(text, match, pattern)) {

        cout << match[1] << endl;

        text = match.suffix().str();

    }

    return 0;

}
```

I expect the output:

```
1111
```

```
2222
```

But I'm getting in output only: 1111
Where is my fault ?

Comment: Are you certain that `xxx22n22yyy` is a match for your regex expression `start_delimiter + "([0-9]+)" + end_delimiter`?  You may need to explain why you expect the output that you do.

Comment: As @DrewDormann stated, your regex is looking for the pattern `xxx[one or more digits]yyy`, so it doesn't match with `22n22`.

Comment: Put another way, the output you are getting is correct.  And it is not clear why you are expecting different output.

Comment: @DrewDormann just I want to extract only digits between tow strings. For example delimiter1 + string+digits+ delimiter2.   I want to extract digits. I thought \d takes only digits and ignore the rest.

Comment: This would be much easier to do without a regular expression.

Comment: You would be better served breaking your problem into smaller chunks rather than trying to do it all in one shot with regex.

Comment: The question asked here, _"Where is my fault?"_ has the answer **your regex**.  It looks for patterns that only have numeric digits between the delimiters.  But you are claiming that's not actually what you want.  If you are struggling with regex, consider not using regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, delimiters **xxx** and **yyyy** are statics, **randomstring** isn't static so it can be any random string.
So the error simply is in your regex pattern.
it should something like this:

```
regex pattern("xxx.*?(\\d+).*?yyy");
```

The whole code could be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main() {
std::string text = 
"xxxrandomstring2222yyy xxx1111yyy";
std::regex pattern("xxx.*?(\\d+).*?yyy");
std::smatch match;


while (regex_search(text, match, pattern)) {

    std::cout << match[1] << std::endl;

    text = match.suffix().str();

}

return 0;
}
```